# Spring java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy.getMediaTypes()Ljava/util/Map;

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-security

I am getting the following error as in stack trace. I just did the maven clean/rebuild thereafter started getting this error. 
I tried few of the suggestions from other similar question: [Error creating bean with name defaultServletHandlerMapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28823600/7413530) and [Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34522622/7413530) but none of the solution worked.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-01-12 18:34:49.883 ERROR 13404 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy.getMediaTypes()Ljava/util/Map;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at com.solambda.kronos.timesheet.TimesheetWebApplication.main(TimesheetWebApplication.java:60) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy.getMediaTypes()Ljava/util/Map;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy.getMediaTypes()Ljava/util/Map;
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.initPathExtensionStrategy(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:307) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.afterSingletonsInstantiated(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:298) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry.getHandlerMapping(ResourceHandlerRegistry.java:148) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:453) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7d35fc5f.CGLIB$resourceHandlerMapping$40(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7d35fc5f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a8ada992.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7d35fc5f.resourceHandlerMapping(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
... 19 common frames omitted

2017-01-12 18:34:49.885  INFO 13404 --- [DB4j\data\50718] ch.vorburger.mariadb4j.DB                : cleanupOnExit() ShutdownHook quietly deleting temporary DB data directory: C:\Users\Abhinay\AppData\Local\Temp\MariaDB4j\data\50718
2017-01-12 18:34:50.215  INFO 13404 --- [DB4j\data\50718] ch.vorburger.mariadb4j.DB                : cleanupOnExit() ShutdownHook quietly deleting temporary DB base directory: C:\Users\Abhinay\AppData\Local\Temp\MariaDB4j\base
```

Here is my main class :

```
 @EnableAutoConfiguration
 @Configuration
 @Import({ TimesheetWebApplicationConfiguration.class,      EmbeddedDBConfiguration.class })

public class TimesheetWebApplication {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TimesheetWebApplication.class);

@Autowired
private MissionInfoServiceClient missionServiceClient;

@Autowired
private UserCompanyContactServiceClientMockImpl userCompanyContactServiceClient;

@Autowired
TimesheetDao timesheetDao;

@Autowired
TimesheetInputDao timesheetInputDao;

@Autowired
TimesheetDayDao timesheetDayDao;

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TimesheetWebApplication.class, args);

}

@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner(final Flyway flyway) {
    return args -> {
        if (args.containsOption("migrateDB")) {
            LOGGER.info("Executing database migrations");
            flyway.migrate();
        }

        if (args.containsOption("insertTestData")) {
            LOGGER.info("Inserting test data for local testing");
            // TODO
        }

         // populating data here 

    };
}
```

}

Comment: You are mixing spring versions 4.3.2 and 4.3.3 never mix jars from different versions. Basically fix your dependencies.

Comment: I have just added the dependency in maven and it's fetching them automatically. spring-web and some other spring packages are on  release 4.3.2. What you suggest to do ?

Comment: apparently they aren't... So you must be specifying a different version some where. Add the pom to your question. Your stack trace clearly states that you are using `spring-context-4.3.2` and `spring-mvc-4.3.3` those don't match.

Comment: thanks @M.Deinum. There were some conflicts in spring version. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Today，I have a test on Spring-boot 1.5.1.RELEASE , and I catch the same problem..

I found ,in SpringBoot 1.5.1.RELEASE defined spring-web spring-context was an old version,then I defined 2 artifact about　spring-web and spring-context in my pom.xml to consistent keep pace with other spring-xx's version

just type flow :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

then it works well.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error as the OP when attempting to use Spring Boot v1.5.2 in my application. In the POM file, none of the Spring JAR versions were overridden except for the Spring Web dependency.

Before:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        .
        .
        .
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version> 
        </dependency>
        .
        .
        .
    </dependencies>
```

I removed the version element from the Spring Web dependency.  This ensured that all Spring artifacts were on version 4.3.7, and the NoSuchMethodError exception no longer appeared on application startup.

After:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        .
        .
        .
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        .
        .
        .
    </dependencies>
```